# Lucene how can i make slop in collocation

Tags: java, lucene

I have a text:

```
TextWord[0]: word0
TextWord[1]: word1
TextWord[2]: word2
TextWord[3]: word111
TextWord[4]: Word
TextWord[5]: Kite
TextWord[6]: word5
TextWord[7]: World
TextWord[8]: word6
TextWord[9]: anti
TextWord[10]: terrorist
TextWord[11]: operation
TextWord[12]: word1212
TextWord[13]: word1231313
```

And i want to find "anti terrorist" with slop=0 and "operation" with ones slop=1, i mean that something like that:

```
query = (" \" \"anti (slop = 0) terrorist\" (slop=1) operation \"~1)
```

When i use (or something like that):

```
Query query = queryParser.parse("\"\"anti terrorist\"~0 operation\"~1");
```

I have result, my query is found, when:

```
TextWord[9]: anti
TextWord[10]: terrorist
TextWord[11]: operation
```

But when text:

```
TextWord[9]: anti
TextWord[10]: badWORD1
TextWord[11]: badWORD2
TextWord[12]: terrorist
TextWord[13]: operation
```

My query found too, but i don't want it, because that's my start rules.
I don't know how can i create slop = 0 in str = "anti terrorist" and make slop = 1 for
str "anti terrorist" (slop = 1) operation.

---

How can i make this?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. My best guess is that you want `"anti terrorist" AND "anti operation"~2 AND "terrorist operation"~1` - so the word `operation` will be no more than one move away from the phrase `anti terrorist`. Or, another guess, perhaps you just want `"anti terrorist operation"` (the exact phrase).

Comment: I think i meant your first option: word "operation" will be no more than one move away from the phrase "anti terrorist"